# UICollectionViewCell imageView doesn't load without scrolling

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell, calayer

I have some cells in my collectionView, oriented vertically. 
Every cell has got an image in it's left part and that image loads correctly.

But after I added a rounded top-right corner to the image doesn't automatically load when the screen in on.
Here is the method that is being called in `cellForItemAt`

```
func setAvatarImage(imageName: String) {
        self.addSubview(avatarImageView)
        layoutIfNeeded()
        avatarImageView.layer.roundCorners(corners: [.topRight], radius: UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad ? 85 : 40)
        avatarImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        avatarImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        avatarImageView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.height.equalToSuperview()
            make.width.equalToSuperview().multipliedBy(0.5)
            make.left.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }
```

Here is also the `roundCorners` method, CALayer extension, which worked perfectly on every element in my app. Also here it works perfectly but the images are not loading without scrolling up and down in the collectionView:

```
func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat, borderWidth: CGFloat = 0, borderColor: UIColor = .clear) {
        let maskPath = UIBezierPath(
            roundedRect: bounds,
            byRoundingCorners: corners,
            cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius)
        )
        
        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = maskPath.cgPath
        
        mask = shape

        let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        borderLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
        borderLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth
        borderLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
        borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        borderLayer.frame = self.bounds
        addSublayer(borderLayer)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding:

```
layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Please *edit your answer* to say where it needs to be added.